# Texto de ANSI para utf-8

Tags: sql-server

Queria saber se tem como converter texto que eram utf-8 e foi colocado em ANSI, com isso ele deu erro e no lugar de acentos, está outras letras totalmente bagunçadas e códigos

Gostaria de saber se tem algo assim no sql server, mas se não, qualquer aplicativo ou site serve.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com ANSI (American National Standards Institute)? Não conheço nenhuma codificação de caracteres denominada ANSI. A tabela ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) contempla apenas 128 sinais e caracteres (7 bits). Caso esteja se referindo à vulgarmente conhecida como "tabela ASCII estendida" então pesquise pela série ISO-8859-x, onde x varia de 1 a 16, que utilizam os outros 128 caracteres passíveis de serem representados em um byte para caracteres específicos de uma série de línguas (ISO-8859-1 é Europeu Ocidental).

Comment: Atualmente recomenda-se o uso do UTF-8 que mapeia os cerca de 109 mil caracteres definidos pelo padrão teórico do consórcio UNICODE.

Comment: @anonimo Apesar do termo ANSI ser vago, ele é amplamente utilizado e normalmente refere-se ao codepage Windows-1252.

Comment: Neste caso é só fazer a conversão apropriada entre os sistemas de codificação.

Answer (score 1):

Nas versões do SQL Server atualmente suportadas pela Microsoft é recomendada a utilização da codificação UTF-16.

> O Unicode é um padrão para mapear pontos de código para caracteres.
>   Como é projetado para abranger todos os caracteres de todos os idiomas
>   do mundo, não necessita de páginas de código diferentes para lidar com
>   os diferentes conjuntos de caracteres. Se você armazenar dados de
>   caractere que refletem vários idiomas no SQL Server (SQL Server 2005
>   (9.x) ao SQL Server 2017), use tipos de dados Unicode (UTF-16) (**nchar,
>   nvarchar e ntext**) em vez de tipos de dados não Unicode (**char, varchar
>   e text**).

**Referência**: [Suporte de Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017#Unicode_Defn)

A título de curiosidade, em versões muito antigas do SQL Server (ex. SQL Server 7.0 ou 2000), utilizava-se Unicode UCS-2. Era então necessária a conversão entre UTF-8 e UCS-2, esta [referência](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/232580/description-of-storing-utf-8-data-in-sql-server) fornece algumas das opções de como se lidava com o problema.